# Visual Studio empty line above declarations

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Like I wrote in the title my Visual Studio puts empty lines above my declarations and I can't find the setting to disable it.

[image]

Hope you guys can help me, thanks alot.

Comment: Do you have resharper or a similar add-in that tries to manage formatting?

Comment: No i just installed visual studio, I also tried to reset all of the settings but didn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

Weird! Looks like [CodeLens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx) annotations don't show up. Try to disable it:

```
Tools → Options → Text Editor → All Languages → CodeLens
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like CodeLens trying to add it's stuff.

To turn off CodeLens, go to Tools | Options | Text Editor | All Languages | CodeLens and uncheck "Enable CodeLens"